# Unable to select a value from angular dropdown list for a default

Tags: html, angular, typescript, default-value, cascadingdropdown

In order to provide a country list for users to select when they fill in address info. I designed an address ngForm to collect the address. Besides, the form also works for users to editing their address info, that means if address exists, all the existing values will be patched first. That means that the existing address elements, such as country name, will need to be in the top of the country list or simply picked up one from the country list as default... that is the user's county will shows up whenever the users open their address info. They should also be able to change to another country by picking one from the list.

With below html and ts code, I could hardly make it for user's existing country displaying as default.

```html
<form #addressForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addressForm.value)">    
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-1">
        <button [disabled]="!addressForm.valid || !addressForm.dirty" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            <span style="font-size: 0.8em">Save Address</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    ......
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="state">State/Province/Region:</label>
            <select
                id="state" class="form-control" name="State" [(ngModel)]="state">
                <option *ngFor="let state of states let i = index"
                    [selected]="i === 0"
                    [ngValue]="state">{{state}}
                </option>
            </select>            
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">   
            <label for="country">Country:</label>
            <select
                id="country" class="form-control" name="Country" [(ngModel)]="country"
                (change)="onCountrySelected($event.target.value)"> 
                <option *ngFor="let country of countries let i = index"
                    [selected]="i === 0"                    
                    [ngValue]="country">{{country}}
                </option>
            </select>            
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="zipcode">Zip Code:</label>
            <input
         ......                
        </div>         
    </div>
</form>
```

component.ts

```js
getCountries() { 
    this.accountService.getUserAddress().subscribe((resp: IAddress) => { 
      this.address = resp;

      if (this.address.country !== null)
      {
        this.memberService.getCountries().subscribe((resp: ICountry[]) => {
          for (let country of resp)
          {
            this.countries.push(country.name);  
          }          
          this.countries = [this.address.country, ...this.countries];
          this.states = [this.address.state, ...this.states];
        });
      } else {
        this.memberService.getCountries().subscribe((resp: ICountry[]) => {
          for (let country of resp)
          {
            this.countries.push(country.name);  
          }
          this.countries = ['', ...this.countries];          
        }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        });  
      }
    });
  }  

  onCountrySelected(countryIdx: any) {
    this.countryId = parseInt(countryIdx);
    this.memberService.getStates(this.countryId).subscribe((resp: any[]) => { 
      this.states = [];     
      for (let state of resp) 
      {
        this.states.push(state.name);
      } 
    });
  }

  onSubmit(addressFormValues) { 
    console.log(addressFormValues); 
    this.accountService.updateUserAddress(addressFormValues).subscribe((address: IAddress) => {         
        this.toastr.success('Address saved');
      }, error => {
        this.toastr.error(error.message);
        console.log(error);
      });  
  }
```

Alternatively, I also tried assigning country's index got from the countries list so as to directly pick the country as selected at the beginning. That seemed not working as well.

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

correspondingly change the selected in html as:

```html
<option *ngFor="let country of countries let i = index"
                    [selected]="i === countryIndex"
                    [ngValue]="country">{{country}}
</option>
```

I also tried [selected]="address.country === country", I could still failed to get user's existing country value as default selected.
Apart from this issue, all the collected address data can be successfully submitted to back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in

```
<option *ngFor="let county of countries let i = index"
                    [selected]="i === countryIndex"
                    [ngValue]="country">{{country}}
</option>
```

you should use county instead of country.

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. The issue remains whether I use [selected]="i === 0" or [selected="i === countryIndex" after clearing the typo.

Comment: @canbrian Sorry a bit late but did you change the ngValue aswell? also selected is just a optional attribute i think. So try [attr.selected]="i === countryIndex". I think you need only one option tag with a selected attr and not selected="true|false"
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp